# Can't connect EMR Pyspark to Kinesis Stream - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, amazon-kinesis

I'm using Pyspark on EMR and trying to connect to Kinesis as per the guide here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kinesis-integration.html

I've been running:

```
spark-submit --jars '/usr/lib/spark/jars/spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.12-3.2.1.jar' kinesis_wordcount_asl.py sparkEnrichedDev abc_decoded https://kinesis.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com eu-west-2
```

but get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hadoop/kinesis_wordcount_asl.py", line 76, in <module>
    ssc, appName, streamName, endpointUrl, regionName, InitialPositionInStream.LATEST, 2)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/kinesis.py", line 116, in createStream
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o65.createStream.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/kinesis/clientlibrary/lib/worker/InitialPositionInStream
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisUtilsPythonHelper.createStream(KinesisUtilsPythonHelper.scala:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.InitialPositionInStream
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 13 more
```

Other users with the same issue seem to say it's an issue with versions but the jar downloaded from [maven](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.12) is for Spark 3.2.1 and Scala 2.12 which is the same version as mine.

I've also had the same error when trying to run spark-submit with the packages flag `spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.12:3.2.1`

I've also tried running similar code in Jupyter Notebooks and tried numerous ways to reference the jar/packages but the error is the same.

Any ideas please?

Comment: There is no guide under that link.

Comment: Thanks @gre_gor I've updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add hadoop-aws dependency to work:

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.12:3.0.1,org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.0.1,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.4 job.py
```